# How can I import an Android project from the android website to eclipse?

Tags: android

A project like this 
Creating a Navigation Drawer
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
tel me how step by step thank you

Answer (score 1):

Download the sample program to your local directory. Open your eclipse -> File -> Import -> Android -> Existing code into Android workspace. Goto the path where the sample program in downloaded and select it. 
Your program will be there in eclipse

Comment: i do not understand this step !

Comment: The link you provided has a sample app right. Download it, and follow the steps I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these links  :

[http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-importproject.htm)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=So-ImZPwTXg

https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/

Comment: hello my question is simple !

Comment: my question is very simple go to this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html  dowlood the exemple and tell me how i can open it widh exlipse step by step